# Classifying a program as compute intensive based on performance counters

Tags: linux, performance, parallel-processing, profiling, perf

I'm trying to classify few parallel programs as compute / memory/ data intensive. Can I classify them from values obtained from performance counters like ***perf***. This command gives couple of values like number of page faults that I think can be used to know if a program needs to access memory frequently, else otherwise.

Is this approach correct and possible way. If not can someone guide me in classifying programs into respective categories.

Cheers,
Kris

Comment: Depending on the depth of the detail you are looking for you may find packages that exist to do what you are needing.  Allinea Performance Reports (http://www.allinea.com/products/performance) developed by my company gives this categorization and analysis - it doesn't focus on things like page faults but it does analyze instructions - such as vector operations, memory reads - and it also measures the parallel (MPI) communication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should in theroy be able to do that with perf. I don't think page faults events are the one to observe if you want to analyse memory activity. For this purpose, on Intel processors you should use uncore events that allow you to count memory traffic (read/write separately). On my Westmere-EP these counters are  `UNC_QMC_NORMAL_READS.ANY` and `UNC_QMC_WRITES_FULL.ANY`

The following article deals exactly with your problem (on Intel processors):

http://spiral.ece.cmu.edu:8080/pub-spiral/pubfile/ispass-2013_177.pdf